# Hide all other same child component in click of one child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a custom Picker component using `Touchable Opacity` and `Picker`. On click of touchable opacity component, the related Picker toggles. I am using this component multiple time in one parent with different data.

Picker's toggle state `isPickerOpen` defined and used in the child component to reduce the complexity of state management in the parent component. I'm required to click on each touchable opacity to show and hide its related Picker.

Here is the code of child component:

```
function CustomPicker(props) {
    const {listItem, callbackParent} = props;
    const [isPickerOpen, setPickerOpen] = useState(false);

    const pickerListItem = listItems.map((item, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} label={item.text} value={item.value} />
    });


    return (
        <View>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pickerButton}
                onPress={() => setPickerOpen(!isPickerOpen)}>
                <Text>Title</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>

          {isPickerOpen && <Picker onValueChange={(value) => 
              callbackParent(value)}>
              {pickerListItem}
          </Picker>
        }
      </View>
   );
}
```

And the parent component fraction:

```
<SelectionPicker listItems={list1} onPickerSelection={handleChange} />
<SelectionPicker listItems={list2} onPickerSelection={handleChange} />
<SelectionPicker listItems={list3} onPickerSelection={handleChange} />
```

How to manage the child component's state on click of touchable opacity, to hide all other open picker, and show just one related picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an external variable to have another form of validation for the Picker component, something like this:

```js
function CustomPicker(props) {
    const {
        listItems,
        onPickerClick,
        onPickerSelection,
        selectable = true,
        name,
    } = props;
    // 
    const [isPickerOpen, setPickerOpen] = useState(false);

    const pickerListItem = listItems.map((item, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} label={item.text} value={item.value} />
    });


    return (
        <View>
           <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.pickerButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    // calling our picker selection function
                    onPickerClick(name)
                    setPickerOpen(!isPickerOpen)
                }}
            >
                <Text>Title</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>

          {(isPickerOpen && selectable) && <Picker onValueChange={(value) => 
              onPickerSelection(value, name)}>
              {pickerListItem}
          </Picker>
        }
      </View>
   );
}

// Our selection handling function
handleSelection(name) {
    this.setState({
        currentPicker: name,
    })
}

// Adding unique names, a validation prop, and a selection method
<SelectionPicker
    name="someNameA"
    selectable={'someNameA' === currentPicker}
    onPickerClick={handleSelection}
    onPickerSelection={handleChange}
    listItems={list1}
/>
<SelectionPicker
    name="someNameB"
    selectable={'someNameB' === currentPicker}
    onPickerClick={handleSelection}
    onPickerSelection={handleChange}
    listItems={list2}
/>
<SelectionPicker
    name="someNameC"
    selectable={'someNameC' === currentPicker}
    onPickerClick={handleSelection}
    onPickerSelection={handleChange}
    listItems={list3}
/>
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks for the solution. Perhaps it's not working exactly as expected. I have added a total of 5 pickers on my parent page. While the component load for the first time, all picker show/hide as expected on click of other picker's button. However when clicking on a button -> related picker opens -> select an option -> click on another button, related picker opens ->  previous opened picker will get close(good) ->  Now click back to the previous button won't open its picker. on the second click of that button, it's related picker opens.

Comment: I removed `setPickerOpen(!isPickerOpen)`  and it's related variable completely from child component and managed the hide/show logic altogether in parent component.